# Attempting to create a CV creates a redirect loop (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, google-chrome

Whenever I try to create a CV from the profile option, Chrome hits the below URL and in response I get the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnUrl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fjobs%2fcv%2fcreate

[image]

Is this a problem with my computer or is this a bug?

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. Did you try another browser?

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: no its fine now.